# Where to place a variable in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables

Error: "Type error Object(...) is not a function"

I'm trying to debug this line of code that I want to iterate over, but it does not work:

```
{
    shuffleAndPick(images, 3).map((image) => (
        <div className="key" key={image.id}>
            <h3>{image.name}</h3>
            <h3>{image.sanskritname}</h3>
            <p>{image.description}</p>
            <img src={image.image} alt={image.name} />
        </div> 
    ))
}
```

I want to do the debugging by setting the shuffleAndPick() function with a value into a variable. And then console.log() the variable to see what I get. In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
const shuffledArray = shuffleAndPick(images, 3)
console.log(shuffledArray)
```

shuffleAndPick

```
const shuffleAndPick = (array, amount) => {
  return array.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()).slice(0, amount);
};
```

My problem is that I dont know where in my code I should put the variable and the console.log.And I only get errors. The code that I want to debug looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useParams } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { shuffleAndPick } from '../helpers/shuffleAndPick'

const URL = 'http://localhost:8080/chakra'

export const Energy = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const history = useHistory()

  const fetchSolarPlexus = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/chakra/5e6c096afe1b75409f5c6133/asana')
      .then (res => res.json())
      .then((json) => { 
        setImages(json)
      })
  } 

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSolarPlexus()
  }, []);  


  return (
    <section className="WorkOut">
      <h2>Energy</h2>
      {shuffleAndPick(images, 3).map((image) => (
        <div className="key" key={image.id}>
        <h3>{image.name}</h3>
        <h3>{image.sanskritname}</h3>
        <p>{image.description}</p>
        <img src={image.image} alt={image.name} />
        </div> 
      ))}
      <button onClick={() => history.goBack()} className="backLink">
        Back
      </button>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Where should I place the variable I want to console.log?

Comment: Put it before the `return`

Comment: Thank you! I tried that but that invokes errors

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? That sounds like an issue with the function. Note that it will be called initially with an empty array, so if you're not handling that possibility within ```shuffleAndPick```, that could be your problem.

Comment: Aha ok I get "Type error Object(...) is not a funtion"

Comment: this is my shuffleAndPick code: 

```
const shuffleAndPick = (array, amount) => {
    return array.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()).slice(0, amount);
  };
```

Comment: Have you tried dropping a `debugger` in your component and step through it?

Comment: No, how do I do that? :)

Comment: Place `debugger` somewhere in your function before the return and when your app is running in the browser it will stop at that line and allow you to step through your code while it is running. You can see the values stored in all previously executed lines of code. [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)

Comment: Thanks I will try that :)

Comment: Also, what errors are you receiving? And where are they originating from?

Comment: I get "Type error Object(...) is not a funtion"

Comment: Just tested your `shuffleAndPick` function implementation with an empty array and it's good, returns empty array (as expected). I don't see in any of the code you shared anything referencing `Object`. Are you sure the error is from this component? Do you have a browser console stack trace you could share? Is `shuffleAndPick` exported/imported correctly?

Comment: Omg! I did forget to add export to const. Thank you sooo much for the help you solved my problem! :)

Comment: Awesome. BTW, what IDE/linter are you using? I feel like any basic setup should have pointed that issue out to you immediately.

Comment: I think I have something called es lint, is that what you mean? :)

Comment: Yes, eslint is a really (*probably the most*) common javascript linter. Either way, glad you got your issue resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is to but the test variable before the return.

I also got alot of help debugging.

Se the comments for more info.